# Where does the difference in size come from?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I created a trie of sorts to store all the words (not definitions) in the English dictionary. The point of it was so that I can get all the words that only contain letters within a given range.

The text file containing all the words is about 2.7 mb, but after creating the tree and writing it to a file using pickle, the file is >33 mb.

Where does this difference in size come from? I thought I would be saving space by not needing to store multiple copies of the same letter for different word, e.g for the words app and apple I would only need 5 nodes, for a -> p -> p -> l -> e.

My code is as follows:

```
import pickle

class WordTrieNode:
    def __init__(self, nodeLetter='', parentNode=None, isWordEnding=False):
        self.nodeLetter = nodeLetter
        self.parentNode = parentNode
        self.isWordEnding = isWordEnding
        self.children = [None]*26 # One entry for each lowercase letter of the alphabet

    def getWord(self):
        if(self.parentNode is None):
            return ''

        return self.parentNode.getWord() + self.nodeLetter

    def isEndOfWord(self):
        return self.isWordEnding

    def markEndOfWord():
        self.isWordEnding = True

    def insertWord(self, word):
        if(len(word) == 0):
            return

        char = word[0]
        idx = ord(char) - ord('a')
        if(len(word) == 1):
            if(self.children[idx] is None):
                node = WordTrieNode(char, self, True)
                self.children[idx] = node
            else:
                self.children[idx].markEndOfWord()
        else:
            if(self.children[idx] is None):
                node = WordTrieNode(char, self, False)
                self.children[idx] = node
                self.children[idx].insertWord(word[1:])
            else:
                self.children[idx].insertWord(word[1:])

    def getAllWords(self):
        for node in self.children:
            if node is not None:
                if node.isEndOfWord():
                    print(node.getWord())
                node.getAllWords()

    def getAllWordsInRange(self, low='a', high='z'):
        i = ord(low) - ord('a')
        j = ord(high) - ord('a')
        for node in self.children[i:j+1]:
            if node is not None:
                if node.isEndOfWord():
                    print(node.getWord())
                node.getAllWordsInRange(low, high)



def main():

    tree = WordTrieNode("", None, False)

    with open('en.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            tree.insertWord(line.strip('\n'))
    with open("treeout", 'wb') as output:
        pickle.dump(tree, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    #tree.getAllWordsInRange('a', 'l')
    #tree.getAllWords()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The size of a node is _much_ larger than the size of a single character in a string.

Comment: How can I make this better? I don't necessarily care about the space but I want to store it instead of building the tree every time.

Comment: Use a dictionary (the python data structure `{}`, nothing to do with the English dictionary) mapping letters to nodes instead of a list. It will also be easier to code with: no need for `ord` and such. If you're not only interested in implementing it for yourself then google "Python trie" and you will find libraries and such to see how others have done it.

Comment: The most important part is to retrieve words within a certain range. I think this is most efficient time wise because I have precise indexing to the nodes in the given range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nodes of a trie are huge as they store a link for all possible next letters. As you can see in the code, every node holds a list of 26 links (children).

More compact schemes are possible (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Compressing_tries), at the expense of more complexity and slower speed.